# Storing a property value into another table

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I am looking for a way to copy the value of some properties of a class to another table in DB. Is there any particular way that I can mark properties of a class as one which their values need to be stored in 2 places (one as part of its own domain object and the other in another domain object, say Summary)?

I a having a Audited entity as below:

```
public class Audited 
{
    public virtual int Id{ get; set; }

    public virtual string FieldName{ get; set; }

    public virtual string FieldValue{ get; set; }
}
```

And other entities such as:

```
public class Plan : FullAuditedEntity
{
    [ToBeAudited]
    public virtual int PlanName{ get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I am looking for a way to be able to mark properties of classes with an attribute (eg. [ToBeAudited]) so that property value gets copied into the Audited table in on insert or update

I have added the [Audited] (`Abp.Auditing`) to `PlanName` and getting the following error in log:

> ERROR 2018-04-20 10:02:09,286 [5    ] Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Abp.EntityHistory.EntityHistoryHelper.ShouldSavePropertyHistory(PropertyEntry propertyEntry, Boolean defaultValue)
>      at Abp.EntityHistory.EntityHistoryHelper.GetPropertyChanges(EntityEntry entityEntry)
>      at Abp.EntityHistory.EntityHistoryHelper.CreateEntityChangeInfo(EntityEntry entityEntry)
>      at Abp.EntityHistory.EntityHistoryHelper.CreateEntityChangeSet(ICollection`1 entityEntries)
>      at Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpZeroCommonDbContext`3.d__98.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.d__20.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkBase.d__57.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Uow.AbpUowActionFilter.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__10.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__23.MoveNext()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage on ABP's [Entity History](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-History) feature (which already works without this customization).

This answer assumes `Audited` is an `Entity` to easily use `IRepository`, but it doesn't have to be:

```
public class Audited : Entity
{
    public virtual int EntityId { get; set; }

    public virtual string FieldName { get; set; }

    public virtual string FieldValue { get; set; }
}
```

First, implement [`IEntityHistoryStore`](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-History#about-ientityhistorystore):

```
public class MyEntityHistoryStore : IEntityHistoryStore
{
    private readonly IRepository<Audited> _auditedRepository;

    public MyEntityHistoryStore(IRepository<Audited> auditedRepository)
    {
        _auditedRepository = auditedRepository;
    }

    public async Task SaveAsync(EntityChangeSet entityChangeSet)
    {
        foreach (var entityChange in entityChangeSet.EntityChanges)
        {
            var entityType = entityChange.EntityEntry.As<EntityEntry>().Entity.GetType();

            foreach (var propertyChange in entityChange.PropertyChanges)
            {
                var property = entityType.GetProperty(propertyChange.PropertyName);
                if (property.IsDefined(typeof(ToBeAuditedAttribute)))
                {
                    await _auditedRepository.InsertAsync(new Audited
                    {
                        EntityId = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(entityChange.EntityId),
                        FieldName = propertyChange.PropertyName,
                        FieldValue = propertyChange.NewValue
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, replace the service and add to [`Selectors`](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-History#configuration) in the `PreInitialize` method of your module:

```
// using Abp.Configuration.Startup;

Configuration.ReplaceService<IEntityHistoryStore, MyEntityHistoryStore>();
Configuration.EntityHistory.Selectors.Add(
    new NamedTypeSelector(
        "ToBeAuditedEntities",
        type => type.GetProperties().Any(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(ToBeAuditedAttribute)))
    )
);
```

Then, just `Insert` as usual:

```
_planRepository.Insert(new Plan
{
    PlanName = 42
});
```

`Audited` table:

[image: Auditeds]

Comment: Fixed in ABP v3.6.